# How do I recover a file from the deleted hdd partition after installing windows 7 ultimate?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, software-rec

I had a file with my important data on it in my previous windows 7 professional. I formatted the partition on which windows was installed and split it into 4.

Now I want to recover the file from the previous partition that was deleted.  Can this be done? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try software like [minitool partition wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/) as shown [here](http://www.partitionwizard.com/help/partition-recovery.htm). But I don't really think it will work because you have created other partitions that fill the disk.

Comment: i tried many recovery softwares nothing worked :/
Btw thanks for your recommendation

Comment: @FarhanKarim - If those tools didn't work then the file CANNOT be restored.  The file has already been overwritten with data.